# Change max line length of GNU parallel

Tags: limit, gnu-parallel

The following command:

```
parallel --max-line-length-allowed
```

returns 131049.

Is this a constant, or can I somehow change this limit?

Comment: So it looks like [this is dynamically obtained](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/src/parallel#n10881), by running `true xxxx...x` (with `x` repeated a varying number of times in a binary search). The limit comes from outside `parallel`, from your shell, perhaps, or OS-level limits

Comment: @StefanosKargas Can you say a little about why you need the limit lifted? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am using it to echo JSON messages coming from a server. And there are messages that reach over 1,5 MB each. The messages I cannot control. They belong to a 3rd party API

Comment: @StefanosKargas Try explaining that in a separate question. I believe `--pipe` may be able to fix that for you.

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by a limit in `execve`. I have not found any way to change it.

However, in CygWin/MSYS2 it seems this limit is lifted to 12MB.

Comment: I think this is a property that is set in the Linux kernel. I don't see how zsh can override this.